# Wget TLS 1.2 error

Tags: wget, ssl

According to the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options.html), I should be able to specify TLS version 1.2 when using wget.

When I try, it fails.

```
wget https://site --no-check-certificate --secure-protocol=TLSv1_2
wget: --secure-protocol: Invalid value ‘TLSv1_2’.
```

If I use `wget https://site --no-check-certificate --secure-protocol=TLSv1`, it works just fine.

Version information:

```
wget --version
GNU Wget 1.15 built on linux-gnu.

+digest +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file +nls +ntlm +opie +ssl/openssl 

Wgetrc: 
    /etc/wgetrc (system)
Locale: 
    /usr/share/locale 
Compile: 
    gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSTEM_WGETRC="/etc/wgetrc" 
    -DLOCALEDIR="/usr/share/locale" -I. -I../../src -I../lib 
    -I../../lib -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -I/usr/include -g -O2 
    -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat 
    -Werror=format-security -DNO_SSLv2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -Wall 
Link: 
    gcc -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat 
    -Werror=format-security -DNO_SSLv2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -Wall 
    -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -L/usr/lib -lssl -lcrypto 
    -ldl -lz -lidn -luuid ftp-opie.o openssl.o http-ntlm.o 
    ../lib/libgnu.a 

Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Originally written by Hrvoje Niksic <hniksic@xemacs.org>.
Please send bug reports and questions to <bug-wget@gnu.org>.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As written on the project page of wget, the secure protocols `TLSv1_1` and `TLSv1_2` were added in wget version 1.16.1. Your wget 1.15 does not support it.

Ressources:

- http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=8159

Comment: FWIW, this feature has since been back-ported to wget-1.14 in CentOS7/RHEL7. The range of TLS versions is detected at build time, so it is possible to have only TLS1.0 and not TLS1.2 support, depending on the OpenSSL library version.

Answer (score 4):

You are using wget 1.15.

It seems, you need at least wget 1.16.1 for this, because one of the noteworthy [changes](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=8159) in that release was:

> - Add --secure-protocol=TLSv1_1|TLSv1_2 .